# Flowplayer + Lightbox2 - only one of those working on one page

Tags: lightbox, flowplayer, lightbox2

As in title, I can't get flowplayer to work on the same page with lightbox2 (I use this last one to display galleries). When I put lightbox2 and flowplayer js's at the beginning of the page, nothing works. If I put only flowplayer js's, it works, the same with lightbox2. Anyone know how to put these to in a way, which both of them would work?

UPDATE:

I don't believe it was so easy. I only change "$" to "jQuery" in flowplayer script in page ($(function() {flowplayer("id" ...  to  jQuery(function() {flowplayer("id" ... ) - and it worked!